# git log over ssh remote repository

Tags: git, ssh, iterator, git-log

I want to create a git (web) browser, hence I need to iterate over commits (`git log`) on remote repository which is on ssh connected machine.
My repo is quite big and constantly changing, therefore I will be interested in not fetching changes locally only to `git log` them.

I have tried with:

```
git remote add origin ssh://example.net/repo
git checkout -b master --track origin/master
```

and it failed :\

Any hints how to do that?

Comment: Why not use git log from an ssh session?

Comment: Local fetches will not be that expensive. Once your original clone is made, I would recommend that you keep a local clone to do all this tracking with.

Answer (score 2):

You could push the log to the web server using a hook. On the repository host create a script:

```
repo.git/hook/post-receive
```

where `repo.git` is your repository path. If anyone pushes to this repository the hook will be triggered and it could dump git log to file and send it to the web server over ssh.

The solution has advantage that anyone having access to web server wouldn't get immediate access to the repository.

Comment: That's very good hint, however I have read only rights to main repository, however I am able to ask someone to do it for me. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe adding crontab entry to pull, and save logs to the db would speeds things up.

Answer (score 0):

On the remote machine, `cd` to your repository and do a `git instaweb`. That will start up a web server that you can access which will contain logs and all other things which are generally used. `git help instaweb` for details.

Comment: I need to interact with those logs (save messages to database and generate PDF reports). However I have stumbled upon a solution using RSS/Atom feed to fetch this info. Now I have an authentication problem on which I am still working on :} _thank you_ nevertheless question is still open

Comment: I Would still recommend that you use a local clone.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run git log over ssh in a cronjob:

```
ssh example.net git --git-dir=repo log > /tmp/repo.log
```

This way you don't need to create local repository copy. This assumes you have ssh keys set up and feel safe with this configuration (someone with access to web server could potentially gain access to the repository).

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get an error with the commands that you quote is because you need to run `git fetch origin` after adding the remote in order to create the remote-tracking branch `origin/master`.

Answer (score 0):

Having to fetch to do git log does not always work.
- I have a large repo that I rarely update so I only clone when I need to make a change.  But I'd like to keep up with changes to it.
- I just pushed.  I'd like to double check the remote repo got my change.
and I dont have ssh access but do have git access to the machine.

It seems obvious that:

```
GIT_DIR=node:/path/to/repo.git git log
```

should work for a restricted set of git log switches.

It's one of the few holes in git today, IMHO.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for any remote repository URL that I've tried. Maybe this is no longer in git?

Answer (score -1):

If you would like to run `git log` localy you will need to clone the repository (isn't that what you were trying to do?):

```
git clone example.net/repo
```

Disadvantage is that it will take space to store it on the web server, but any future pull will download only new changes and may be quite fast and will depend on size of changes:

```
cd repo
git pull
```

You could make the `pull` either in crontab or even trigger it from repository host using hook to update it only when needed.

Comment: He's asking about doing it directly from remote repo

Comment: Korayem, he would like to avoid to fetch it, but still it is a valid solution. Also this answer is incorrectly downvoted (if that was you) because it is NOT "sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or ... dangerously incorrect".