# 'git pull' branch only

Tags: git, branch, tracking, git-checkout

I have a git cloned repository.

The purpose of this repo is `git log`, as long there is no such thing as [git log over ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924922/git-log-over-ssh-remote-repository).

```
$ git ls-remote

ac118076af0ca4c164a831b9e31b1a307747ec36        refs/heads/master
db1253eae8241aa0813d5a49880c41cd810216c2        refs/heads/production/version-2011.10
32c2dcad3133c8214c0d0e898e32b7a7a9f068cf        refs/heads/release/version-2011.11
```

I would like to set-up a read-only branch only for `git pull` from remote machine (tracking branch?!).

```
$ git branch -tb version-2011.11 refs/heads/release/version-2011.11

fatal: git checkout: updating paths is incompatible with switching branches.
Did you intend to checkout 'refs/heads/release/version-2011.11' which can not be resolved as commit?

$ git checkout -tb version-2011.11 release/version-2011.11

fatal: git checkout: updating paths is incompatible with switching branches.
Did you intend to checkout 'release/version-2011.11' which can not be resolved as commit?
```

In future:

- release/2011.11 will become a production/2011.11
- master -> release/version-2011.12
- and so on...

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

`git ls-remote` shows you the refs in the remote repository, so `refs/heads/release/version-2011.11` is only a valid ref in that repository, not your local clone.  If the remote is called `origin` (as it would be by default) then your corresponding remote-tracking branch will be called:

```
refs/remotes/origin/release/version-2011.11
```

... or you can use the abbreviation: `origin/release/version-2011.11`  (The error you can see is from git trying to interpret the last parameter as a path, since it doesn't know of a ref with that name.)

If you just want to use `git log`, then you don't even have to create a local branch that tracks the remote-tracking branch - you can just do:

```
git log origin/release/version-2011.11
```

To update that remote-tracking branch (in case there have been changes in the remote repository) you can just do:

```
git fetch origin
```

Comment: however I will still need a repository clone, right? It is quite huge. Thank you anyway, I'll try.

Comment: The premise of your question was that you had a repository clone.  If you just need the output of git log, and you can ssh to the machine, just do `ssh me@wherever git --git-dir=/srv/git/blah.git log`